# Why is "((TextView) mySpinner.getSelectedView()).setError(null)" giving an nullPointerException error on phone rotation?

Tags: android, orientation, android-spinner

In my android project I have used `((TextView) mySpinner.getSelectedView()).setError(null)` to set error to a spinner. When the activity gets loaded at first it works well but when the user changes the orientation or rotates the phone, the activity crashes due to using this statement (I have tested this by commenting and uncommenting this statement).

Now, how can I use this statement and also prevent the activity from crashing?

Comment: Can you share where did you initialize the `mySpinner` ?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine At the staring of `onCreateView()` method, before using `mySpinner.getSelectedView().setError(null)`. As you can see I am using mySpinner inside a fragment.